# String and Enumerable.Count

Tags: c#, .net, string

In the documentation for [Enumerable.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx) we see that a special case is handled if the source implements `ICollection<T>`

> If the type of source implements ICollection, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count.

and this is visible in the [implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1191) thereof :

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;
    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null) return collection.Count;
    int count = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        checked {
            while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now, lets look at `string`. The `String` class has the following signature :

```
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IEnumerable, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEquatable<string>
```

We can see here that it does not implement `ICollection` as it is immutable.

Therefore calling `Enumerable.Count` on a `string` will iterate over the entire string every time even though it is immutable.

So my question is, why is there a special case for `ICollection` but not for `String`.

Comment: How often are you working with an "unknown" implementation of `IEnumerable<char>` vs. the number of times you're working with something you know, specifically, to be a `string` and can therefore simply access `Length` on it?

Comment: `ICollection` is an interface which is implemented by all collection types, so it is logical to do such optimization for these types. but it wouldn't make sense to specialize a generic method considering a single type. if you do this optimization for strings, then another question arises, why not do this for all types that has a `Lenght` property?

Answer (score 2):

This is only going to get opinion-based answers, but I suspect people don't often use `.Count()` on strings.

Also, every additional type you support specifically slows down Count for the types without a specific implementation.

So while it is perfectly possible for the implementation to take string into account, I suspect the designers chose it wasn't worth it.